# Storing datetime in mysql using yii framework

Tags: mysql, datetime, yii

I have created datetime field in mysql. I want to store it in the db when i pick the date by using datepicker.

This is my part of code in controller

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
    $model=new EmpDetails;
    $model->created = date("Y-m-d H:i");
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['EmpDetails']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['EmpDetails'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view ','id'=>$model->emp_id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

The part of my form.php is:

```
  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'dateof_leave'); ?>
        <?php $model->created=new CDbExpression('NOW()');
        $sqldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($textFieldValue));?>
           <?php
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'dateof_leave',
            'htmlOptions' => array(
            'size' => '10',         // textField size
            'maxlength' => '10',    // textField maxlength
            ),
            ));
            ?>
    <?php // echo $form->textField($model,'dateof_leave'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'dateof_leave'); ?>
</div>
```

am facing the error Property "EmpLeave.created" is not defined.

Please clarify my doubts and explain me how can i overcome this issue?

Comment: which line shows error?

Comment: show the structure of emp_leave. It appears that the field 'created' does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$model->created=new CDbExpression('NOW()');
```

On

```
$model->created=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Because CJuiDatePicker needs string on input.

Comment: still am facing CException property EmpLeave.created is not defined??  whether i have to replace created to date field name(which i have given in my db) in my controller.

Comment: `created` has to exists in your database to use it in your model. If your `created` field has an other name in your database, name it that way.

Answer (score 0):

In yout Controller you add line

```
 $model->created = date("Y-m-d H:i");
```

In your _form.php you add input form for `dateof_leave`. So when posting form the `$model->created` is EMPTY. If i am understand right In controller u must add

```
 $var= $_POST['EmpDetails']['dateof_leave'];
 $model->created = date("Y-m-d H:i", $var);
```